# Stable Sort in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I wrote a stable sort algorithm in C#.  It is just a simple iteration, and is probably not very optimal:

```
static void StableSort(ref ObservableCollection<string> Vals, ref ObservableCollection<int> Weight)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Vals.Count; i++)
  {
    int LargestVal = -1;
    int LargestValIndex = 0;

    for (int j = i; j < Vals.Count; j++)
    {
      if (Weight[j] > LargestVal)
      {
        LargestVal = Weight[j];
        LargestValIndex = j;
      }
    }

    if (LargestValIndex != i)
    {
      Weight.Insert(i, Weight[LargestValIndex]);
      Weight.RemoveAt(LargestValIndex + 1);

      Vals.Insert(i, Vals[LargestValIndex]);
      Vals.RemoveAt(LargestValIndex + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

You can see how it works by running it with this code (this isn't what I want a review on, but if you see something really wrong, please tell me):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  ObservableCollection<int> i = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7, 3, 3, 7 };
  ObservableCollection<string> s = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2a", "4a", "6", "7a", "2b", "4b", "7b", "3a", "3b", "7c" };

  foreach (int item in i)
  {
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();

  foreach (string item in s)
  {
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();

  StableSort(ref s, ref i);
  Console.WriteLine();

  foreach (int item in i)
  {
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();

  foreach (string item in s)
  {
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This is going to be integrated into a larger project that requires that I use `ObservableCollection`s.  At the most, there will probably be 20-50 values being sorted, but this is going to be run on phones and other devices without a lot of computing power, so I would also like to know if this should be optimized or if a different sorting method should be used to improve performance.  A stable sort isn't absolutely required, but I would much prefer it.  Thanks for any tips ahead of time!

Comment: Sorting is *hard* and probably deserves proper unit tests.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. Sure. Sorry. I mean it would be better to `Assert` that you're getting the expected answer using a unit testing framework than to visually check it by writing results results to the console. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

Comment: Sorting is hard so unless you are 100% confident with your solution then I suggest you use the sort methods that come with the .net framework for your production code.

Comment: If my developers were to write a sorting algorithm then I demand them to also write a 50 page document fully describe their code and why they choose to reinvent the wheels rather then using one of the exisiting methods provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible problems**

- you don't check for `Vals == null` nor for `Weigth == null`
- you don't check if `Vals.Count == Weight.Count`
- a object which subscribed the `CollectionChanged Event` of the collection, will get much work

**Guard condition**

If we replace

```
if (LargestValIndex != i)
{
    //do the swapping
}
```

by

```
if (LargestValIndex == i) { continue; }

// do the swapping
```

we will save a level of indention.

**Naming**

- Based on the [naming guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) parameters and local variables should be named using `camelCase` casing.
- Because an `ObservableCollection` will by its nature contain multiple items, a parameter representing one should be named using the plural form.

**Refactoring**

Implementing all above will lead to

```
static void StableSort(ref ObservableCollection<string> values, ref ObservableCollection<int> weights)
{
    if (values == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }
    if (weights == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("weights"); }
        
    if (values.Count != weights.Count) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("collections count not equal", (Exception)null); }

    IList<string> localValues = new List<string>(values);
    IList<int> localWeights = new List<int>(weights);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
    {
        int largestWeight = -1;
        int largestWeightIndex = 0;

        for (int j = i; j < values.Count; j++)
        {
            if (localWeights[j] > largestWeight)
            {
                largestWeight = localWeights[j];
                largestWeightIndex = j;
            }
        }

        if (largestWeightIndex == i) { continue; }

        localWeights.Insert(i, localWeights[largestWeightIndex]);
        localWeights.RemoveAt(largestWeightIndex + 1);

        localValues.Insert(i, localValues[largestWeightIndex]);
        localValues.RemoveAt(largestWeightIndex + 1);
    }

    values = new ObservableCollection<string>(localValues);
    weights = new ObservableCollection<int>(localWeights);

}
```

now that it is a clean implementation we are finished.

But wait, we can do better.

We can use the `OrderByDescending()` extension method together with `Select()` extension method and anonymous types.

```
static void StableSort(ref ObservableCollection<string> values, ref ObservableCollection<int> weights)
{
    if (values == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }
    if (weights == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("weights"); }

    if (values.Count != weights.Count) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("collections count not equal", (Exception)null); }

    IList<string> localValues = new List<string>();
    IList<int> localWeights = new List<int>();

    int index = -1;
    var weightsWithIndex = weights.Select(p => new { Value = p, Index = ++index }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Value);

    foreach (var w in weightsWithIndex)
    {
        localWeights.Add(w.Value);
        localValues.Add(values[w.Index]);
    }

    values = new ObservableCollection<string>(localValues);
    weights = new ObservableCollection<int>(localWeights);
}
```

So, what is this fancy, cool stuff

```
weights.Select(p => new { Value = p, Index = ++index })
```

??

We create for each item in `weights` a `anonymous type` where we create a property `Value` and assign the item of `weights` and before we assign the `index` to the `Index` property we increment it. So basically this is just like creating a `Tuple` but a way cooler.

Some related information

- by definition `anonymous types` are immutable.
- the order of properties matters

  ```
    var p1 = new { X=1, Y=2 };
    var p2 = new { X=1, Y=2 };
    var p3 = new { Y=2, X=1 };
  ```

here `p1.Equals(p2) == true` but `p1.Equals(p3) == false`

An extract from a [good reading](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128001041/http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx) about this subject

> In short, an anonymous type is a reference type that derives directly
> from object and is defined by its set of properties base on their
> names, number, types, and order given at initialization.  In addition
> to just holding these properties, it is also given appropriate
> overridden implementations for Equals() and GetHashCode() that take
> into account all of the properties to correctly perform property
> comparisons and hashing.  Also overridden is an implementation of
> ToString() which makes it easy to display the contents of an anonymous
> type instance in a fairly concise manner.

Comment: Hmm I wonder what kind of algorithm is under the hood of `OrderByDescending`. Nice answer(as always).

Comment: @RubberDuck check it out : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7eec09816d04e761

Comment: Way ahead of Ya. =;)-